How can I enable Bootstrap RFS for headings only?
RFS is great, but in my case I only need to use it on elements with very large title words, such as h1, h2, etc.
I don't want RFS to be used on my buttons or other elements. I have set $enable-rfs: false;.
Besides deleting @include font-size from each scss file one by one, is there a better way?

The usage documentation implies that RFS is enabled manually with mixins. Isn't that working?
